# HTC One stuck on bootloader

Tags: htc-one-x, htc-one, htc-one-s

I badly need help. Last week I was able to convert my HTC One to GPE, and today I want to restore it to its factory ROM so I can restore the warranty as well. Now the problem I am facing is that when I tried to S-Off my device now its stuck to bootloader with ***TAMPERED***, ***RELOCKED***, and ***Security Warning*** messages on top of bootloader. How can I boot my device to CWM Recovery which I had previously installed?